# Dependence of the focal length of converging lenses on the absolute index of refraction

Tags: optics, lenses

How will the focal length of a converging lens change if it is replaced by one having a greater absolute index of refraction?

Answer (score 1):

To find the change qualtitatively you can use lenmakers equation

See here at wikipedia 
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens%23Lensmaker%27s_equation&ved=2ahUKEwiCmfjKvf7nAhWFfH0KHbLmAqkQygQwAHoECAMQBg&usg=AOvVaw0zSBRU3tPFvSAcXw16Utck&cshid=1583244687471

Comment: Just replace the refractive indices with new ones

Comment: I also thought about Lensmaker's equation but wasn't sure. Thank you!

Comment: I think its worth noticing that if the refractive index of outer medium is greater than that of material of lens it will change its nature.(converging to diverging and vice versa)  Also always happy to help :-)